# Embedded or an External ActiveMQ Broker with Glassfish

Tags: glassfish, jms, activemq-classic, glassfish-3

This would be my first time using ActiveMQ (instead of the out-of-the-box OpenMQ in GF) and I am trying to determine which approach is better in terms of scaling and maintaining an ActiveMQ environment. We do have experience in setting up and maintaining Glassfish clusters and deploy applications to it. But we are contemplating on what approach is better as we don't want to go down a rabbit hole that we can't get out of because we built environments around it and seeing towards the end that the infrastructure we had setup wouldn't scale.

Has anybody tried using both approaches? Even if anybody implemented one of the approaches with Glassfish, telling us their experience (gains and pains) would be very helpful and appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For 99% of cases, it's usually better to deploy a standalone broker - this way you're treating your messaging as just another layer of the infrastructure, much like a database. When a broker is standalone, you can set it up as highly available, upgrade it at will without modifying your applications (a broker can be upgraded without upgrading the client libraries), and can scale it out as appropriate later on if you need to (most projects don't).

I have seen people deploy brokers as embedded, with a convoluted network of brokers to get all the boxes in a cluster talking to each other. This usually ends in tears and reverting back to a separate master-slave pair of brokers. Which is all they needed all along.